# Allow only one instance of Inno Setup without prompting

Tags: inno-setup

I need to allow only one instance of Inno Setup. I used `SetupMutex`, but when I run the second setup it will prompt the user. I need the setup do nothing and close without any prompt, if another instance is running.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28628699/7571258

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I do not think that what you are trying to do is an improvement to a user experience, quite on the contrary, anyway...*

---

Remove your [`SetupMutex` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupmutex) and use this code instead:

```pascal
[Code]

const
  SetupMutexName = 'MyProgSetup';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CheckForMutexes(SetupMutexName) then
  begin
    Log('Mutex exists, setup is running already, silently aborting');
    Result := False;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Creating mutex');
    CreateMutex(SetupMutexName);
  end;
end;
```

*(There's a negligible chance for a race condition between `CheckForMutexes` and `CreateMutex`)*