# concurrency between OS processes

Tags: delphi, concurrency

The problem is over-complicated. A much straightforward solution is to redesign as Uwe and David suggested:

(1) Worker app.
(2) Long-running TcpServer, that awaits clients and calls workers
(3) Clients.

========================

I would like to build a `SampleApp` that functions as:

- When started, it checks if there is already `SampleApp` running;
- If not, it starts a `TcpServer`, a `TcpClient`, passes certain command from its `TcpClient` to its `TcpServer`, does the work, closes the `TcpServer`, and quits;
- If yes, it starts a `TcpClient`, passes the command to the other's `TcpServer` and quits. (The other's `TcpServer` will do the work.)
- There may be multiple `SampleApp` started when the first one is still running.

---

I have no idea about how to solve this problem practically, for example :

1. Which architecture to start with ? ( The reputed OmniThreadLibrary seems to deal with thread-based concurrency instead of OS-process-based concurrency. )
2. There is no `SampleApp` running. Two `SampleApp` are started (almost) simultaneously. How to guarantee only one TcpServer is started? (There is no "global list" to register the incoming "players".)
3. There is one `SampleApp` running. How to handle if a 2nd detects the 1st's mutex and thus decides to be a TcpClient, but the 1st stops its TcpServer and quits?

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I ensure only a single instance of my application runs using Delphi XE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390412/how-to-i-ensure-only-a-single-instance-of-my-application-runs-using-delphi-xe) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459554/how-can-i-tell-if-another-instance-of-my-program-is-already-running etc.  OTL is not the answer here.

Comment: That thread seems to give no solution to my problem. For example, how to deal if the 2nd detects the 1st's mutex and thus decides to be a TcpClient, but the 1st stops its TcpServer and quits?

Comment: I don't see that scenario in your question.

Comment: You will **always** have a little overhead time in startup/shutdown, so the possibility of one not seeing the other can never be prevented, only minimized.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry I did not explicitly mention the scenario. I listed two example problems, and thought `process-based concurrency` could mean more. I would think strictly speaking, singleton/mutex is not concurrency anyway.

Comment: @JanDoggen Never? I thought there must be some way. (For example, in text books, concurrency is crucial for banks. There should be no leaks at all?)

Comment: Singleton/mutex is synchronization. Which appears to be a large part of what you want to do. If you synchronize then your not explicitly mentioned scenario cannot arise.

Comment: Why not start the tcpserver as a service when Windows starts and let it run forever?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Great! Could you help to comment how to synchronize between OS-processes? (For example, to synchronize within thread, one has critical section.)

Comment: Use a mutex or a semaphore for between process synchronisation. And as Uwe says, be prepared to consider different overall designs.

Comment: @UweRaabe I hesitate because the quality of this `SampleApp` is only amature grade. I mean, multiple `SampleApp` will be run automatically. I don't know what to do with the in-coming clients do if the TcpServer is started as service, raises one exception and halts? If the TcpServer is started at the same time as `SampleApp`, error cases will not hurt so much.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Great! I will try to learn how to use mutex or semaphore for inter-process synchronization.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Singleton/mutex is synchronization. Which appears to be a large part of what you want to do. If you synchronize then your not explicitly mentioned scenario cannot arise." Could you please be more specific? Sorry but I still don't know how to handle the "lap" between "checking mutex" and "server quits/client tries to connect", after checking various wiki definition links.

Comment: I don't understand your problem well enough to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this primarily to communicate between processes on a single computer (in a single user session), you should like at ActiveX Automation Objects. Creating a COM object that uses a LocalServer will do the starting and stopping of the 'server' process for you.

See more here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Creating_an_Active_Server_Object

In case you insist on using TTcpServer, when two processes start (almost) simultaneously, still only one is allowed to bind to a certain TCP port, and the other will get an exception when calling Listen on the TTcpServer.